# C - When I use fopen() to create a file, where is that file located?

Tags: c, fopen

I'm new to programming, and I'm having difficulty with `fopen()` and such.
When I run

```
FILE* file = NULL;

file = fopen("HereIAm.txt", "w");
```

Where is `HereIAm.txt` created? Where do I need to look for that new file?

Comment: In the current directory. Why don't you try?

Answer (score 3):

**That file is created in the current [Working directory](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Working_directory) of your program.**

You can use the `getcwd` function (look up how to use it) to print where exactly that is, or even change it with a similar function.

Now, the working directory would realistically either be:

**1)** The directory that your compiled executable was compiled in, or

**2)** The directory that was set in your debugger, if you run your program from an IDE like Visual Studio.

The 1st option is most likely if you don't use an IDE. Find where the .exe file that you run is and you will also probably find the text file. If it's not there, check your project's debugging path settings in the IDE you use.

*Note:* You can append `~/` in front of your file's name (so that its `"~/HereIAm.txt"` if you want it created in your `home` directory (in Unix, not sure in Windows, maybe C:/Users/(your username))

Comment: `/HereIAm.txt` would be in the root folder, `~/HerIAm.txt` would be in the user's home folder.

Answer (score 2):

It's created in the path you specify as the first argument to fopen. See `man fopen`. If you don't specify a full path, and only a file name, then it's the current directory.

Comment: For what it's worth, he didn't specify that he was using *nix, so `man fopen` might not be an option for him.

Comment: To extend that a bit more, he didn't specify any OS, and there are OS out there that don't have the notion of a "current directory". So the location the file is going to end up is system dependent.